# don't work HMSegmentedControl with storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to install in my project this example SegmentedControl, I went to Old-fashioned wai (Add HMSegmentedControl.h and HMSegmentedControl.m to my project.) Created and put the code of ViewController (from example project) in MyViewController.n and MyViewController.m, after the launch there was such an error - how to fix it?

```
    2015-03-24 16:50:34.170 gfhfgh[455:7040] Unknown class Map in Interface Builder file.
2015-03-24 16:50:34.782 gfhfgh[455:7040] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8baa75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f553bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f780c78 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7dfbe4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   gfhfgh                              0x000000010d859963 -[Map2ViewController viewDidLoad] + 2435
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e3b4580 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010e3b477e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010e957f4e -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 65
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010e38fd69 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010e3c0531 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1746
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010e3c2871 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010e3c2795 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010e28fa22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e396e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010e39621f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010e2d5b68 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010e2d6493 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010e2a2fb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010e2b0227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010e28b23c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7efc91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7e5b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7e5194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7e4bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111652a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010e28e580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    26  gfhfgh                              0x000000010d8769b3 main + 115
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111181145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

After removal of the class card error occurred

```
    2015-03-24 17:41:22.081 gfhfgh[576:7945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eaa6a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e73fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e96cc78 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9cbbe4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   gfhfgh                              0x000000010ca45963 -[Map2ViewController viewDidLoad] + 2435
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d5a0580 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d5a077e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010db43f4e -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 65
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d57bd69 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d5ac531 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1746
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d5ae871 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d5ae795 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d47ba22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d582e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d58221f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d4c1b68 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d4c2493 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d48efb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d49c227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d47723c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9dbc91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9d1b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9d1194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9d0bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011083ea58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d47a580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    26  gfhfgh                              0x000000010ca629b3 main + 115
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011036d145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EDIT :
Highlighted in green this line, the application stops, thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

```
HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl2 = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionImages:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"4"]] sectionSelectedImages:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1-selected"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2-selected"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3-selected"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"4-selected"]]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `Map` class to any object in your storyboard or xib.

Remove `Map` class see the image[image]

EDIT : Now you have a following error, which tells you that you are trying to insert nil object to an array or dictionary.

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

To track this error add an exception breakpoint and run the project. (As shown in below image)

[image]

Now You have an error on following line:

```
 HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl2 = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionImages:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"4"]] sectionSelectedImages:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1-selected"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2-selected"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3-selected"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"4-selected"]]];
```

This means one of your image is `nil`. Check all images in your bundle.

Comment: I do not have the reputation that would publish the picture - this is a link to it http://cl.ly/image/241y230X2e0L?_ga=1.129299722.701167339.1426154549 , I had already been done

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that you want to remove the class

Comment: @N J Gadhiya I removed the class as in the picture, but it did not help

Comment: @N J Gadhiya Updated the question

Comment: @N J Gadhiya please, see my edit, i update the question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an unknown class `Map in your interface builder`. It is the `UIView` of this View Controller:

[image: VC].

You should either remove the `Map` (like N J Gadhiya showed) or create a class `Map` that inherits from `UIView`, depending on what you want to do.

Did you add a `UIMapView` to your storyboard/xib? If so, you need to add a class to your project `Map` that inherits from `UIMapView`.

If you have defined another item as having class `Map`, then you have to create a class `Map` that inherits from the type that element is from.

Comment: No, did not add, now try

Comment: Can you post your `Interface Builder file`?

Comment: http://cl.ly/2Q0K1x2F0K0K?_ga=1.90856860.701167339.1426154549 this my project - look at a group of map and map the button

Comment: I removed the class as in the picture of N J Gadhiya , but it did not help